# DataTable.Load() is taking too much time compared to SqlDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have to implement an asynchronous DB connecting method with DataSet, so first I tried to use SqlDataReader to fill DataSet. But it takes way too much time.

Here's the codes :

Using DataTable.Load

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (!reader.IsClosed)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.BeginLoadData();
        //////////////////////////////////////
        dt.Load(reader);     // takes too much
        //////////////////////////////////////
        dt.EndLoadData();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
}
```

Using SqlDataAdapter.Fill

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    ...
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```

I think these two methods do exactly same thing. But when reading 2400 rows in DB the first method takes 20ms in average, otherwise the second one takes just 7ms.

Is there something that I've missed or is the code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `SqlDataAdapter::Fill(DataSet)`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Clear();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();           
dt.Load(reader);             
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: The code has to be like the above one because the result of ExecuteReader() may has multiple tables. Anyway I tried like yours but the result is same.. dt.Load() takes much longer than adapter.Fill().